# Observer pattern in the era of lambdas

Tags: c++, design-patterns, lambda

The [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) traditionally requires the **observer** to implement an `update()` method.

However, when we have **lambdas** we can alternatively do this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Subject
{
public:
   using CallbackClosure = std::funtion<void()>;
   void RegisterCallback(CallbackClosure&& cb) {
      closures_.push_back(std::move(cb));
   }

   void test() {
       for (auto const& cb : closures_) {
           cb();
       }
   }

private:
   std::vector<CallbackClosure> closures_;
};

// usage
int main()
{
   Subject s;
   // register here with a lambda instead of a pointer to the observer
   s.RegisterCallback([]{ std::cout << "Hey from main\n"; }
   s.test();

   return 0;
}
```

I know that of course we could make the `RegisterCallback` be a p*ure virtual* and let different subjects impl. that interface, but the above should be enough to illustrate the example.

Is this the modern way of doing the **observer pattern**? Or is there some benefit in defining an update interface for the **observers** as well?

Can the lambda simply be seeing as an anonymous observer?

Comment: No you should not make it a pure virtual... you should make it a template.  Also allow for registration of lmabdas `template<typename fn_t> raii_registration = RegisterCallback(fn_t fn);` And retrun an RAII object representing the registration so you can revoke it too.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, Great idea returning a RAII object! Do you have any source of this idea (asking in the hope of more good ideas from that source), or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, Regarding making it a template, do you mean to make the whole class a template (since the std::vector must use the stored callback type as well)?

Comment: Design patterns are often expressed in terms of OOP languages like Java simply because these languages are popular. C++ is a multi-paradigm language, there's no need to use OOP solutions to problems OOP created. To me, design patterns are conveying intent, not specific implementation; or as they are usually defined, "a solution to a common problem". When I see name "Observer" or "Pub/Sub", I know what the problem was and the general idea for the solution, to get the details I'll read documentation/implementation.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I completely agree, but I wanted to sanity check with you experts in cased I missed something in my observation about simplifying the "traditional" approach.

Comment: I never said anything about using std::vector ;)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Also C++ has something most other languages lack and that is templates/static polymorphism. But yes the pattern naming is language independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very close to beddtime here, but this is a very quick draft of what I am thinking of. (Note symbols placed in namespace details are usually not intended to be used by client code directly)

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{

struct revoke_itf_t
{
    virtual void revoke(std::size_t cookie) = 0;
    virtual ~revoke_itf_t() = default;
};

struct subscription_t
{
    std::size_t cookie;
    revoke_itf_t* subscriptions;
    
    // todo bool flag and move constructor

    ~subscription_t()
    {
        subscriptions->revoke(cookie);
    }
};

}

template<typename... args_t>
class callbacks_t :
    public details::revoke_itf_t
{
public:
    [[nodiscard]] auto subscribe(std::function<void(args_t...)> callback)
    {
        m_subscription_id++;
        m_subscriptions.insert({m_subscription_id,callback});
        return details::subscription_t{m_subscription_id,this};
    }

    void operator()(args_t&&... args)
    {
        for(auto& [cookie,callback] : m_subscriptions)
        {
            callback(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        }
    }

private:
    void revoke(std::size_t cookie) override
    {
        auto it = m_subscriptions.find(cookie);
        if ( it != m_subscriptions.end() )
        {
            m_subscriptions.erase(it);
        }
    }

    std::size_t m_subscription_id{0ul};
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t,std::function<void(args_t...)>> m_subscriptions;
};

int main()
{
    callbacks_t<int> subject;

    {
        auto subscription = subject.subscribe([](int value) { std::cout << value << "\n"; });
        
        subject(1);
        subject(2);

        // subscription goes out of scope here
    }

    // so callback is not called here anymore
    subject(3);
}
```

Comment: Scandinavia here, so same for me.
Thanks a lot for the effort here. Really useful!

Comment: It is a draft because for production code I would even check some more things, The registration object should have a flag indication deregistration is still needed and a move constructor, the class is not threadsafe and the register function I would make it a template only accepting noexcept functions (your callback mechanism can't handle exceptions)

Comment: may I ask why you chose unordered_map over fx vector?

Comment: I did this so I could unregister easily by cookie (id). If I would use an index into a vector I would need to keep track of the "holes" in the vector after unregistering.

Comment: Because of the memory layout of the vector and my use case (small number [<100] of subscribers + rare subscriber updates), I think the performance is better for the vector.
For unregistering I'll just use `std::erase_if()` (C++20)

Comment: @SupAl That's fair (because deregistration is rare) but then you'll have to have a vector `std::vector<subscription_t>`  not a vector of just std::function

Comment: Yes, I'll make a struct to hold the id + callback.

Comment: @Pipijn Kramer, I see a flaw in the design. The revoke method will cause UB if the Subject goes out of scope before the subscriber. 
I fixed this by adding a shared_ptr<int> in the Subject. Whenever a client subscribes they get a weak_ptr in the struct (that also holds the id + callback). When the registration goes out of scope, it checks if the weak_ptr has expired before unsubscribing. In this way we get a cheap check (only one shared_ptr) and the lifetime of the sub / pub has been decoupled.

Comment: I see it the other way around. That situation should be avoided  and you should be able to control the lifecycles by design. (At least I manage that in vary large code bases).  I tend to keep classes as simple as possible; so no it is not a design flaw but a difference in approach yours will work to