# Find lambda in vector and remove it

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a lambda/reference in a vector, and remove it, but I am getting an error, how can I do this?

> no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const std::function<void()>' and 'const std::function<void()>')

```cpp
using TeardownLogic = variant<function<void()>, Subscription*>;

class Example {
  vector<TeardownLogic> finalizers = vector<TeardownLogic>();

  void add(TeardownLogic teardown) { this->finalizers.push_back(teardown); }

  void remove(TeardownLogic teardown) {
    auto idx = find(this->finalizers.begin(), this->finalizers.end(), teardown);
    if (idx != this->finalizers.end()) {
      this->finalizers.erase(idx);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your basic design is mixing responsibilities.  A function is not a subscription so why make it "polymorphic" with a variant?.
E.g. look to my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929937/observer-pattern-in-the-era-of-lambdas/77930043#77930043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare std::functions.  If you can change your code to use regular (C style) function pointers, or member function pointers, you could compare those.

Comment: Hmm, okay makes sense now. Maybe what I could do is write a wrapper class that I can compare instead and hold the function in there (instead of using c style).